# Trigger a workflow when case is escalated

Tags: workflow, escalation

When a Case is escalated through an Escalation Rule, the standard checkbox field 'IsEscalated' is updated - it is set to true.  This is an update, like any other, and should fire workflows and triggers.  Especially triggers. But why it is not happening ?

Here is the Footprint, How can achieve Workflow changing **Status** to **LATE** ?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seems to be possible, you can vote the idea- [Allow Escalation Rules to trigger field updates or Workflow rules](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000a8g9AAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By referring @rahul-sharma Link , tried work with both OwnerId and IsEscalated Change of field value i wrote workflow formula As below

**Evaluation Criteria   - Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited**

**Rule Criteria-**

```
AND( 
ISCHANGED( OwnerId ), 
IsEscalated =True 
)
```

It is working as i excepted.